# Unable to access Profile scope on Uber API with node-uber wrapper

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to build a project using the Uber API and node, and was using the node-uber wrapper here: https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber

I've been able to access the History scope with no issue, but I'm not able to get the Profile scope. Any insight into what might be wrong? Snippets below.

Thanks!

```js
app.get('/sign-in', function (req, res) {

  var url = uber.getAuthorizeUrl(['history', 'profile']);
  res.redirect(url);
  console.log(url);
});
```

```js
app.get('/oauth/callback', function (req, res) {

  var code = req.query.code

  uber.authorization({ authorization_code: code }, 
    function (err, access_token) {
      req.session.uberToken = access_token
      res.redirect('/my-trips');
    });
});


app.get('/api/profile', function (req, res) {
  uber.user.profile({access_token: req.session.uberToken}, function (err, apiResponse) {
    res.send(apiResponse);
  });

});
```

Comment: What error do you get when requesting the user's profile?
Are you sure you have the profile scope checked in the [dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard)?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show your error message? Based on your snippet, it's hard to understand what might go wrong without making assumptions. One thing that you might check is the authorization within the callback method. More specific, this assignment:

`req.session.uberToken = access_token`

You're assigning the uberToken to the request, which doesn't have any effect. Modifications to the response, however, would be useful. The request property won't exist in the method scope for the `GET /api/profile`. Hence, accessing the profile should return a HTTP 401 (Unauthorized).